# How make dynamically changing dropdowns in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a models something like this.

```
class SchoolForm(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField(Subjects, ...)


class Subjects(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
```

I need to make two dropdowns: first with school form and second with subjects.
If I choose a form in first, I should get options in second dropdown, consisting of subjects, belonging to this form. 
How I can do this? Better do it without reloading page, because it's some kind of filters.

I'm using Python 3.5.1 and Django 1.9

Comment: you can use ajax to load the second dropdown when the first changes

Comment: Is there any other ways..?

Comment: the other way would involve hiding/showing the choices of all the subjects but the one previously selected using javascript, ajax is way simpler and maintainable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @maazza said, the only way to do this using some sort of front-end code. You can use simple Javascript or [django-selectable](http://django-selectable.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html).